# Некорректно работает вывод прокси-серверов и их использование

Tags: golang, proxy

**У меня есть список прокси серверов (8 штук) и мне нужно чтоб при каждом последующем запросом использовался новый прокси сервер (Рандомная связка и выбор)**

Код:

```
package main

import (

    "fmt"
    "time"
    "io/ioutil"
    "math/rand"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {

    rand.Seed(time.Now().Unix())
    randoms := []string {
      "http://37.57.241.120:8888",
      "http://5.228.54.34:8081",
      "http://35.161.5.60:3128",
      "http://200.164.114.202:8080",
      "http://84.200.85.55:8888",
      "http://90.188.43.30:3128",
      "http://103.56.114.90:80",
      "http://195.80.140.212:8081",
    }

    best_ua := rand.Int() % len(randoms)
    for i := 1; i <= 8; i++ {
      fmt.Println(best_ua)
    }

    proxyUrl, err := url.Parse("http://37.57.241.120:8888")
    httpClient := &http.Client { Transport: &http.Transport { Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyUrl) } }
    response, err := httpClient.Get("http://2ip.ru")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    } else {
        body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
        fmt.Println("OK: ", len(body))
        fmt.Println(response.Header)
    }
}
```

У меня не выбирается не один прокси-сервер. Выдает:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

**Как мне при каждом последующем запросе менять прокси сервер чтоб скрыть свой IP?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А в чем проблема?

Вот тут можно сделать так:

```
best_ua := randInt(len(randoms))
```

а тут

```
proxyUrl, err := url.Parse(randoms[best_ua])
```

для генерации при каждом запросе напишите небольшую функцию:

```
func randInt(len int) int {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().Unix())
    return rand.Intn(len)
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Все работает, но когда запихиваю в цикл, действует только один прокси (выбирается один прокси сервер), а как я предполагал будут задействованы все 8 прокси серверов. Каждый новый запрос в цикле на один и тот же url . Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: @JackSmith, попробуйте функцию небольшую написать, добавил в ответ, чтобы при каждом вызове rand.Seed отрабатывал

Comment: не знаю правильно ли я отработал функцию. код - https://pastebin.com/bWAjKucz, но у меня ошибки tcp соединения все время.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Теперь все работает!